# uncaught Error: [Register] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
function App() {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
   
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/">
          {user ? <Home /> : <Register />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">{user ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />}</Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          {user ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Register />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/profile/:username">
          <Profile />
        </Route>
         
        
      </Routes>
      
    
  );
}

export default App;
```